# Isolated storage for audio files not using individual click events

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, audio-streaming

Ive come to realize that packaging all these audio files within the xap was just a bad idea as its now grown to about 60 mb. Id like to no longer package my audio files with the app, rather I'd like to use URLs and have them loaded into Isolated Storage when the user presses the sound buttons. Im unsure how to do this with my app, since my buttons are not coded individually. They are loaded automatically from a view model into LongListSelectors. And play depending on which one is clicked (data.filepath). 
Below, I have attempted to use Isolated Storage but receive errors.

UPDATED mainpage.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    WebClient _webClient;
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;

        //webclient download
        _webClient = new WebClient();
        _webClient.OpenReadCompleted += (s1, e1) =>
        {
            if (e1.Error == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    string fileName = FilePath.
                            Substring(FilePath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1).Trim();
                    bool isSpaceAvailable = 
                        IsSpaceIsAvailable(e1.Result.Length);

                    if (isSpaceAvailable)
                    {
                        // Save mp3 to Isolated Storage
                        using (var isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(
                                fileName, FileMode.CreateNew,
                                IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()))
                        {
                            long fileLen = e1.Result.Length;
                            byte[] b = new byte[fileLen];
                            e1.Result.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
                            isfs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
                            isfs.Flush();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Not enough to save space available to download mp3.");
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e1.Error.Message);
            }
        };
     }

    // Check to make sure there are enough space available on the phone
    // in order to save the image that we are downloading on to the phone
    private bool IsSpaceIsAvailable(long spaceReq)
    {
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {

            long spaceAvail = store.AvailableFreeSpace;
            if (spaceReq > spaceAvail)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
     }
        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar




    // Load data for the ViewModel Items
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
    }

    private void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(
        object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LongListSelector selector = sender as LongListSelector;

        // verifying our sender is actually a LongListSelector
        if (selector == null)
            return;

        SoundData data = selector.SelectedItem as SoundData;

        // verifying our sender is actually SoundData
        if (data == null)
            return;


        if (File.Exists(data.FilePath))
        {
            AudioPlayer.Source = new Uri(
                data.FilePath,  
                UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        }
        else
        {
            using (var storageFolder =
                IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(
                        data.FilePath, FileMode.Open, storageFolder))
                {
                    AudioPlayer.SetSource(stream);
                }
            }
        }

        selector.SelectedItem = null;
```

Here is a bit of my SoundModel model. I left one example of how it is set up now with local storage which works. The other is how id like it to use a url.

```
private SoundGroup CreateGamesGroup()
        {
            SoundGroup data = new SoundGroup();

            data.Title = "Games";
            string basePath = "assets/audio/Games/";

            data.Items.Add(new SoundData
            {
                Title = "Gauntlet Exit",
                FilePath = basePath + "GauntletExit.mp3",
                Groups = "VideoGames"
            });                  

            data.Items.Add(new SoundData
            {
                Title = "Gauntlet Exit",
                FilePath = 
                    "http://k007.kiwi6.com/hotlink/23lenhzr3h/GauntletExit.mp3",
                Groups="VideoGames"
            });
```

Since the Mainpage.cs references the SoundData model, I will add that as well here:

```
 public class SoundData : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string Items { get; set; }
    public string Groups { get; set; }


    public RelayCommand<string> SaveSoundAsRingtone { get; set; }


    private void ExecuteSaveSoundAsRingtone(string soundPath)
    {
        App.Current.RootVisual.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            SaveRingtoneTask task = new SaveRingtoneTask();
            task.Source = new Uri("appdata:/" + this.FilePath);
            task.DisplayName = this.Title;
            task.Show();
        }
            );
    }   

    public SoundData()
    {
        SaveSoundAsRingtone = 
            new RelayCommand<string>(ExecuteSaveSoundAsRingtone);
    }
```

Currently  the url doesnt work as I expected it wouldnt. I get these errors:

**A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.**

Comment: I see you updated your question. Updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's the root cause of your problems, but you need to use `appdata:/` for files included in the XAP, otherwise use `isostore:/`

When you have items bound to LongListSelector via exposed property, you can assign command to your items and handle "clicks" in your viewmodel.

Let's say you have the following in your VM:

```
public ObservableCollection<SoundData> AudioFiles { get; set; }
public ICommand PlayCommand { get; set; }
```

Then related XAML would be something like:

```
<phone:LongListSelector
        x:Name="AudioFilesList" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding AudioFiles}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SoundData}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                <command:EventToCommand 
                    Command="{Binding PlayCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, 
                        ElementName=AudioFilesList}" 
                    PassEventArgsToCommand="False" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Border BorderThickness="2" 
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                            Height="80">
                        <TextBlock 
                            Text="{Binding FilePath}" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Important part above is the LongListSelector's ItemsSource, SelectedItem and binding of PlayCommand.

I set up a small sample project @ Git, hope it helps you figure it out https://github.com/mikkoviitala/any-ringtone

It gets few mp3s over http, saves files into IsoStore and then displays items in LongListSelector. Tapping list item launches command that executes Ringtonetask.

[image: imgur]